# Why does adding an item messes up toolbar in an Eclipse 3.2 Plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am working on an enhancement to add buttons to a toolbar for an Eclipse plugin.  The technology is fairly old. I am using IBM Rational Application Developer 7.0.10.  Here is what I see as far as the versions

```
JDK 1.5
Eclipse Platform 3.2.2
Eclipse Plugin Development 3.2.1
Eclipse RCP 3.2.2
```

When my code adds a new button to the toolbar, it messes up the toolbar.  It only shows some of the buttons and hides the rest.  But when I resize the view even the slightest bit, all the buttons show.  It does not appear to be a case of screen real estate as making the view larger does not help.  I am new to Eclipse plug-in development, so I am not sure what is causing this.  I seem to be doing what is needed to add a button.  I have tried different things, like insertBefore instead of add and so on.  But nothing seems to help.

I wrote some test code (using the sample plugins that come with Eclipse) to isolate the issue, but I have not had success.  I have given the code for 2 classes.

```
// This class is generated from Elipse, to which I have added code
public class MenuBarTestView extends ViewPart {

    // Instance variables ...

   public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
       viewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
       drillDownAdapter = new DrillDownAdapter(viewer);
       viewer.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());
       viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());
       viewer.setSorter(new NameSorter());
       viewer.setInput(getViewSite());

       // Selection change listener, which adds a button to tool bar
       // I added the following line
       viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new TreeSelectionChangedListener(this));

       makeActions();
       hookContextMenu();
       hookDoubleClickAction();
       contributeToActionBars();
   }

   .
   .  // Other Eclipse generated code for the sample plugin goes here
   .
   .

   // I added this method to add a button
   public void addButton () {

       IActionBars bars = getViewSite().getActionBars();
       IToolBarManager tbm = bars.getToolBarManager();

       Action action = new Action() {
          public void run() {
              showMessage("Action 1 executed");
          }
      };
      action.setImageDescriptor(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().
            getImageDescriptor(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_FOLDER));
      tbm.add(action);
      tbm.update(false);

   }
}
```

I wrote the following class for the selection change event

```
package menubartest.views;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelectionChangedListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.SelectionChangedEvent;

public class TreeSelectionChangedListener implements ISelectionChangedListener {

    private MenuBarTestView view;

    public TreeSelectionChangedListener(MenuBarTestView view) {
        super();
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.addButton();
    }
}
```

When the application comes up

[image: This is when application first comes up]

This is upon a selection on the Tree

[image]

This is after an ever so slight resize

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that this is a bug with Eclipse 3.2 (or at least the version bundled with RAD 7.0).  I tried this with Eclipse 3.7 and did not see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to call the `IActionBars.updateActionBars()` method after adding to the toolbar.

Comment: I did the replaced the tbm.update() with bars.updateActionBars() in the addButton method - But it did not help. I also tried calling tbm.update() after bars.updateActionBars().  That did not help either.

Comment: Looking at the Eclipse source I can't really find anywhere that does anything similar to this - normally all buttons are added to the toolbar during the view initialization and are enabled/disabled as required.

Comment: That is perhaps true.  I have a requirement that needs to add/remove buttons.  I have been struggling with this for a while.  It works if I remove all the buttons (removeAll()), do an update() on the ToolBarManager, add the buttons back and do another update() on the ToolBarManager.  However, this makes the tool bar refresh and it is very noticeable.